# tensorflow2.1 inside docker report OOM when creating tf.Variable

Tags: docker, tensorflow2.0

I am new to docker tensorflow2.1. 
Below works:

```
docker run --gpus all -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3 \
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"
> 2.1.0
```

But this one reports OOM:

```
docker run --gpus all -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3 python -c "import tensorflow as tf; x = tf.Variable([1, 2])"
2020-03-24 14:29:34.751582: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libnvinfer.so.6
2020-03-24 14:29:34.771627: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libnvinfer_plugin.so.6
2020-03-24 14:29:35.680313: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-03-24 14:29:35.699963: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-24 14:29:35.700510: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0 name: GeForce MX250 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.582GHz coreCount: 3 deviceMemorySize: 1.96GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 52.21GiB/s
2020-03-24 14:29:35.700557: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-03-24 14:29:35.700588: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-03-24 14:29:35.710006: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-03-24 14:29:35.714535: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-03-24 14:29:35.740218: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-03-24 14:29:35.741996: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-03-24 14:29:35.742047: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-03-24 14:29:35.742147: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-24 14:29:35.742420: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-24 14:29:35.742610: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-03-24 14:29:35.743760: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-03-24 14:29:35.783886: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2299965000 Hz
2020-03-24 14:29:35.784691: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x4290980 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-03-24 14:29:35.784711: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-03-24 14:29:35.799242: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:276] unable to create StreamExecutor for CUDA:0: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 0: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory; total memory reported: 2099904512
2020-03-24 14:29:35.799379: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:136] Ignoring visible XLA_GPU_JIT device. Device number is 0, reason: Internal: no supported devices found for platform CUDA
2020-03-24 14:29:35.799615: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-24 14:29:35.799825: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0 name: GeForce MX250 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.582GHz coreCount: 3 deviceMemorySize: 1.96GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 52.21GiB/s
2020-03-24 14:29:35.799854: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-03-24 14:29:35.799866: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-03-24 14:29:35.799890: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-03-24 14:29:35.799909: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-03-24 14:29:35.799924: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-03-24 14:29:35.799935: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-03-24 14:29:35.799948: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-03-24 14:29:35.800046: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-24 14:29:35.800256: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-24 14:29:35.800430: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-03-24 14:29:35.801613: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 260, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 254, in _variable_v2_call
    shape=shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 235, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kws: default_variable_creator_v2(None, **kws)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2645, in default_variable_creator_v2
    shape=shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py", line 262, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 1411, in __init__
    distribute_strategy=distribute_strategy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 1543, in _init_from_args
    name="initial_value", dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1314, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 317, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 258, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 266, in _constant_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 95, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    ctx.ensure_initialized()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/context.py", line 509, in ensure_initialized
    context_handle = pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_NewContext(opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: CUDA runtime implicit initialization on GPU:0 failed. Status: out of memory
```

Comment: This error occures in spacemacs inferior-shell buffer, but disappears in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see how much GPU memory you have used? (With or without space emacs)

```
docker run --gpus all -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3 nvidia-smi
```

If installed you can also use nvidia-smi outside of docker to see the GPU memory users. (And maybe avoid using some programs concurrently with TF)

The last thing to try would be to look at the memory grow options in [the GPU guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) (search for tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth or TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH and maybe tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration - hopefully that will allow you to run in a restricted GPU memory environment)